# Grails scaffold 404 with byte[]

Tags: grails, groovy, scaffold

I'm trying to upload a file in grails. The generated scaffold is not working for me and giving me a 404 looking for 'save.jsp'

**Domain**

```
class Simple{
  byte [] avatar

  static constraints = {
    avatar nullable: true, maxSize: 1000000
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class SimpleController{
  def scaffold = Simple
  //or
  static scaffold = Simple
}
```

The issue has appeared previously and has been marked resolved here http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSCAFFOLD-69, but I have the issue with grails 2.3.6 on mac OSX.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but scaffold should be defined as static `static scaffold = Simple`

Comment: Hi, thanks @Alidad. Unfortunately that seems to boil down to the same problem. Oddly the file is being uploaded then displayed as an int array in the view rather than a file.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem in Windows. It works flawlessly. Also checked in dbconsole that the data exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks dmahapatro. I'll give it a whirl on a Linux and Windows to check it out.

Comment: by any chance, did you upgrade to 2.3.6 from an earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
static scaffold = true // instead of static scaffold = Simple
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding plugin is separate. Please make sure you are using the latest version in BuildConfig.groovy.

```
compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
```